# Android how to write int values to a buffer and take values from the buffer using a timer?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application which is receiving UDP packets, parsing to an int array and passing to another method. What I need is that, the values should stored in a buffer, then take the values from the buffer and plot in a graph. After that the buffer memory should be freed up. I am not aware on how to save the int array values to a buffer and take the values from the buffer using timer. Could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to solve my issue.
For storing the values to a buffer I have used ArrayList.

```
public void dataFromJnich0(int ch0[] ){
    for (int index = 0; index < ch0.length; index++) {
        ch0Buffer.add(ch0[index]);
    }
    plotGraph();
}
```

Instead of Timer I have used Thread.sleep for solving my issue.

```
    public void plotGraphs() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            addEntryGraph0();
            addEntryGraph1();
            addEntryGraph2();
            addEntryGraph3();
            addEntryGraph4();
            addEntryGraph5();
            ch0Buffer.subList(0, 100).clear();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```